# Nativescript-dev-webpack setup

Tags: webpack, nativescript

I'm working on NativeScript with Angular, now I want to use Webpack on my project to separate the JS and Maps files that generated by NativeScript from ts files. Does anyone have a sample of webpack.config.js?

I want it to be something like this after building the app:

- app

  - assets

    - pages
  - js - JS files are supposed to be here
- components - ts files

Answer (score 0):

Yess you can get the directory setup and running example - https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries

make sure you use the release branch.